# How to compare 2 different columns in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have two columns I'd like to compare data in. The first column has about 50 rows, whereas the second column has 200 rows.

I would like to be able to tell if any cell in the first column matches up with a value in the second column.

I first tried this with the QUERY() function

```
=QUERY(A12:B, "Select A where A = B")
```

but this didn't seem to work, I got a circular dependency error.

I then tried the array function.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(A12:A=B12:B,"REMOVE_ME", "DON'T REMOVE ME"))
```

but this was outputting incorrect values. Is there an easier way to do this or am I missing something?

Here is sample data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IVUksDc79uJPfe6_Yfkp-EBelzh-U3q1EIiYlguQoRw/edit?usp=sharing

The value 6 is given MATCH because there is a value 6 somewhere in Column B.

Answer (score 3):

Use this formula in `C2`:

```
=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(A2,$B$2:$B$22,1,0)>0,"MATCH","NO MATCH"),"NO MATCH")
```

Comment: This only seems to affect a single row, should it be affecting all rows?

Comment: Copy C2 and paste it over C3 to C7